# What's a proper error metric between solutions of 2D PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What's a proper error metric between solutions of 2D PDEs?

For 1D I would maybe take MSE (just a guess).

But in 2D?

Answer (score 1):

Given f(x,y) and g(x,y), I would suggest $\int\int |f(x,y)- g(x,y| dxdy$ as an error estimate.

Comment: Any more rationale? If this is compared to MSE, then are these "equivalent"?